# Rspec, Factory girl and after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test this `after_initialize` callback which is for the `item` model (which has_many `line_items`):

```
after_initialize :build_default_items, unless: :line_items?
```

callback:

```
  def build_default_items
    LineOfBusiness.all.each do |lob|
      line_items.new(line_of_business_id: lob.id)
    end
  end
```

My test looks like:

```
  describe 'callbacks' do
    let(:user) { create :user }
    it 'should build default items' do

      lob1 = LineOfBusiness.create(id:1, name: "Name1", eff_date: Date.today,exp_date: Date.tomorrow,  create_user: user, update_user: user)
      lob2 = LineOfBusiness.create(id:2, name: "Name2", eff_date: Date.today,exp_date: Date.tomorrow, create_user: user, update_user: user)

      lob_count = LineOfBusiness.all.count # this is correct as 2

      item = build :item 

      expect(item.line_items.count).to eq(lob_count)
    end
  end
```

Error message as follows:

```
expected: 2
     got: 0

(compared using ==)
```

So its failing in the callback method, its seeing the `LineOfBusiness.all` as `Nil`

```
  def build_default_items
    LineOfBusiness.all.each do |lob|  # <-- this is Nil so fails
      line_items.new(line_of_business_id: lob.id)
    end
  end
```

Any ideas why its Nil in the callback method?

Comment: If `LineOfBusiness` is empty, then `LineOfBusiness.all` would have given `[]`, instead of `nil`, and `each` loop shouldn't get iterated.

Comment: the loop is not getting iterated, but why is LineOfBusiness empty? you are correct in that the loop is not being iterating, but surely LineOfBusiness.all.count should be 2 like in the test method

Comment: if you change it to  `item = create :item`, does it make any difference?

Comment: In spec, you have used `count` method, which will fire query to database. But in intialize callback, you are not saving `line_items`. Try using `size` method instead of `count` in spec.
`expect(item.line_items.size).to eq(lob_count)`

Comment: size worked!!  please post as the answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line_items.count` will fire query to database, and as you are not saving `line_items` in `after_initialize` callback, spec will fail. Instead try using `line_items.size`.

```
expect(item.line_items.size).to eq(lob_count)
```